# when the height of bar is vety small data lable is not visible in apex chart

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

[image]

As you can see in the above picture. then 2,3,4 element's data lable is not visible. its value is 2,1,1 respectively. since its very less thaan 20 its nit visible. is there a way to fix this?
It is visivle when the value is 3 in the datalable.

```
const series = [
    {
      name: name ? name : ' ' + subName ? subName : ' ',
      data: data?.length > 0 ? data : [0],
    },
  ];

  const barColor = color ? color : '#2564DE';

  const options = {
    fill: {
      opacity: 1,
    },
    colors: [barColor],

    grid: {
      xaxis: {
        lines: {
          show: false,
        },
      },

      yaxis: {
        lines: {
          show: false,
        },
      },
    },
    //data on the x-axis
    chart: {
      stacked: true,
      id: 'bar-chart',
      toolbar: {
        show: false,
      },
    },

    xaxis: {
      categories: categories?.length > 0 ? categories : ['undefined'],
      labels: {
        rotate: 0,
        hideOverlappingLabels: false,
      },

      lines: {
        show: false, //or just here to disable only y axis
      },
      axisTicks: {
        show: false,
      },
      crosshairs: {
        show: false,
      },
      axisBorder: {
        show: false,
      },
    },
    dataLabels: {
      offsetY: -18,
      style: {
        fontSize: '12px',
        colors: ['#304758'],
      },
      formatter: function (value: string) {
        return translatedNumValue(value.toString());
      },
    },
    plotOptions: {
      bar: {
        borderRadius: 0,
        columnWidth: getPercentWidth(300, data?.length, 40),
        dataLabels: {
          position: 'top', // top, center, bottom
        },
      },
    },

    yaxis: {
      axisTicks: {
        show: false,
      },
      crosshairs: {
        show: false,
      },
      axisBorder: {
        show: false,
      },
      lines: {
        show: false, //or just here to disable only y axis
      },
      labels: {
        show: false,
      },
    },
    tooltip: {
      custom: function ({ dataPointIndex }: any) {
        const title = categories[dataPointIndex];
        const value = data[dataPointIndex];

        return `<div class="p-3 bg-primary-white space-y-2">
                    <div class="font-bold">${title?.join(' ')}</div>
                    <div>${name}: <span class="font-bold">${translatedNumValue(
          value.toString(),
        )}</span></div>
                </div>
    `;
      },
    },
  };
```

This Is the seris and options I have used. May be is can be solved by adding a minimum height of the bar, but I could not figure a way to do that too. Is there a way to set min height of the bar?

Comment: As you can see from [this apexcharts example](https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/column-charts/column-with-data-labels/), the datalabels are visible even for very small heights of bars. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/uek3fj4n/) is an extreme example where the bar height is so small that it is not at all visible, but the datalabel is still displayed. Please make the example runnable, e.g., in a SO code snippet or a fiddle, so we can debug and identify the cause  of your datalabels being obscured.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similar issue today with a horizontal bar chart by setting the hideOverflowingLabels property. It must be done in the plotOptions dataLabels object. I'm also noticing your offsetY of -18, this might be contributing to the labels being hidden.

```
plotOptions: {
  bar: {
    borderRadius: 0,
    columnWidth: getPercentWidth(300, data?.length, 40),
    dataLabels: {
      position: 'top', // top, center, bottom,
      hideOverflowingLabels: false
    },
  },
},
```